# Lazy loading data in Entity Framework 6 with MySql not working

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, code-first

I'm working on a code-first EF6 project using MySql. I have setup my data classes such that their related data objects should be lazy-loaded, but they seem to run very slowly each time they are called.

This is an example of one of my entity classes:

```
[Table("Carrier")]
public class DBCarrier
{
    [Key]
    [Column("CarrierId")]
    public int carrierId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128), Required]
    public string CarrierName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DBDepot> Depots { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DBZone> Zones { get; set; }
}
```

But when I call the `Zones` on an object of this class like this (this was all in one statement, but I separated it out to try and find out where the problem was):

```
ICollection<DBZone> zones = carrier.Zones;
IEnumerable<DBZone> zones1 = zones.Where(x => x.Postcode == postcode);
return zones.Select(x => x.ZoneName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Every time I call `carrier.Zones` it takes about 8 seconds to run. I thought that by defining `zones` as an ICollection would delay execution of the database query.

Answer (score 2):

`ICollection` means the data is definitely already materialized in memory. The only way to get your desired behavior is to use an interface which supports deferred execution and there's only two:

- [IQueryable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) the query is built up using `Expressions` and is used to fire queries upon remote data sources (for example sql database).
- [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) the query is built up using `Delegates` and is used to fire queries upon datasets already in memory.

Using any of these 2 interface types will cause your query to be executed when you iterate the data using `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `ToList()` or `ToArray()`.

But seeing you only need the names of the zones your query is pretty inefficient. You fetch the whole `DBZone` object but you only take the name, I would suggest just fetching the names:

```
return carrier.Zones.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Postcode == postcode).Select(z => z.ZoneName);
```

For this you need to keep `carrier` as an `IQueryable` of course.

**Edit:** Just noticed "Every time I call carrier.Zones it takes about 8 seconds to run."

This is the expected behavior for lazy loading. The data will get fetched from the database when you access it => Database call for the carrier, and another call to database for the zones when you access them. This can be avoided using eager loading (`Include` method) to get all the desired data in one trip to the database.

Comment: Makes sense. I will try that later.